# Bind JSON to GridView ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, gridview

i created a function which gives JSON string, I wanted to bind it to Gridview. as json have array inside object so i think maybe it will required nested gridview.
here is my function

```
List<BanquetMenuType> listMenu = new List<BanquetMenuType>();
listMenu = wsobj.GetOrdermenuTypeByOid(OrderID);

for (int i = 0; i < listMenu.Count; i++)
{
    listMenu[i].data = wsobj.GetOrderMenuById(listMenu[i].OrderID, listMenu[i].MenuId);
}

var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(listMenu);
return json;
```

JSON string response is:

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "MenuName": ""
      },
      {
        "MenuName": "baingan"
      },
      {
        "MenuName": "bhendi"
      },
      {
        "MenuName": "paneer TIkka"
      }
    ],
    "OrderID": 24,
    "MenuId": 1,
    "MenuType": "Sabjee"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "MenuName": ""
      },
      {
        "MenuName": "cucmber chips"
      }
    ],
    "OrderID": 24,
    "MenuId": 2,
    "MenuType": "Salad"
  }
]
```

I want to menu name under MenuType 
i dont worked on JSON before so having no idea how to bind it..

Comment: Explain a little bit more: you are sending that JSON to the view ? you are using a RAZOR page ? You won't create a ViewModel for that JSON ?

Comment: its normal website project not mvc but i do have view model for that json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to convert the list object("listMenu") to JSON. It wont work as well.

Data source should be of a type that implements "IEnumerable" interface which List and Array satisfies.

```
List<BanquetMenuType> listMenu = new List<BanquetMenuType>();
listMenu = wsobj.GetOrdermenuTypeByOid(OrderID);

for (int i = 0; i < listMenu.Count; i++)
{
    listMenu[i].data = wsobj.GetOrderMenuById(listMenu[i].OrderID, listMenu[i].MenuId);
}
outerGrid.DataSource = listMenu;
outerGrid.DataBind();
```

And yes, you will need to have nested grid to take care of the *data* property. In the RowDataBound event of the outer grid, you will need to bind the *data* property, to the nested grid. 
Sample code:

```
protected void OuterGrid_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var dataItem = outerGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataItem as BanquetMenuType;
        GridView innerGrid = e.Row.FindControl("innerGrid") as GridView;
        innerGrid.DataSource = dataItem.data;
        innerGrid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can deserialize json using [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) for conversion - Two ways given below

```
string jsonString = "Your JSON string ";   

//Create a dynamic object, here you have to import Newtonsoft.Json 

dynamic dynamicObject= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);  

//Binding GridView to dynamic object   
myGrid.DataSource = dynamicObject;  
myGrid.DataBind();  

//-----OR -----

//Using DataTable, here you have to import System.Data  

DataTable dataTable= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonString); 

//Binding GridView to dataTable object   
myGridTwo.DataSource = dataTable;  
myGridTwo.DataBind();
```